# NodeJS: uploading file to another server along with other data

Tags: node.js, filestream, eventbrite

I am trying to send some data to another server. This includes a file as well. Here is how I am doing it:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request8 = require("request");    
var _value = fs.createReadStream(_completefilePath);//File that needs to be sent.

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: _uploadURL,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }, 
    formData: {
        fileName: {
            value: _value,
            options: { filename: _fileName, contentType: null }
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(_data)//_data is a JSON object
    }
};

request8(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        return 1
    else
        return 0;
});
```

I have tried many times but the error I get is "ECONNRESET". I have no idea what is wrong with the request above? Is it not properly formed or is there any issue on third party server?

Basically I am trying to upload a file to Eventbrite server. The code in Python is given [here](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/resources/uploads/) under step 2 and that's what I am trying to convert in NodeJS.

**[Update 1]: When I changed "formData" to "form" I got statusCode 412(precondition failed).**

**[Update 2]: Changing the code to below gives "Bad Request" error.**

```
var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: _uploadURL,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token
        }, 
        formData: JSON.stringify({
            fileName: {
                value: _value,
                options: { filename: _fileName, contentType: null }
            },
            data: _data
        })
    };
```

Comment: ECONNRESET comes when the connection is reset by the server due to timeout in processing or in this case most probably malformed request, can you share a working curl request with the server you are trying to upload to, I'll give you the nodejs request format and headers required.

Comment: "formData" to "form" I got statusCode 412(precondition failed) is because an http request with enctype = multipart/form-data needs "formData"

Comment: @SaleemAhmed I have maded changes and updated the code above. The working example is given at https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/resources/uploads/ under step 2 Is that fine for you?